# Python setup.py not copying child directories

Tags: python, django, setuptools, distribute

I'm trying to install this:
https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video/

But, for some reason when I try to install it with `python setup.py install` it only installs files in `src/videostream` and none of the files in child directories `src/videostream/management`, `src/videostream/templates`, etc.

I have used setuptools and distutils a few times, but I'm clearly not an expert.

The setup.py is here https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video/blob/master/setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name="videostream",
    version="0.2",
    url="http://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video",
    description="A simple video streaming application for django",
    author="Andre Engelbrech",
    author_email="andre@teh-node.co.za",
    packages=['videostream'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)
```

I've tried replacing the packages list with find_packages() from setuptools but that didn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up solving this by changing the setup.py to:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="videostream",
    version="0.2",
    url="http://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video",
    description="A simple video streaming application for django",
    author="Andre Engelbrech",
    author_email="andre@teh-node.co.za",
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

and adding MANIFEST.in with:

```
recursive-include src/videostream/templates *
```